# Ionic - react how to repeat component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to repeat my component for n times using react in ionic but i don't know how to that

for example in my `Component.tsx` i have:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IonCard, IonCardContent} from '@ionic/react';

const Component: React.FC = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <IonCard>
                <IonCardContent>Hello From Ion Card</IonCardContent>
            </IonCard>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Component;
```

And in my `App.tsx` I have:

```
import { IonApp} from '@ionic/react';
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';
import './theme/variables.css';

import Component from './Component';


const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp className="ion">
    <div>
       {
        // I want to repeat this
      <Component />
       }
    </div>
  </IonApp>
);

export default App;
```

I'm new to typescript and react, I would be so happy if you help

Thanks

Comment: Given a state/number of repetitions, let's say 4, you can do `{Array(4).map(_ => <Component />)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop. The best loop here is `map`:

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <IonApp className="ion">
    <div>
       {
         Array(5).fill(null).map((_, i) => (
           <Component key={i} />
         ))
       }
    </div>
  </IonApp>
);
```

Don't forget that repeated components need to have a unique `key` prop in the loop.

And please pay attention to `.fill(null)`. When you create an array using the `Array` function, it gets filled with `empty` values, and running `.map` method on it will fail. We have to fill it with a value (In this case `null`) in order to make it iterable.